# Can't remove mplayer without removing a bunch of unrelated programs?

Tags: apt, lubuntu, mplayer

When I try to remove `mplayer` from Lubuntu 16.04, the system tries to remove unrelated programs like Bleachbit, Deluge, Virtualbox...

With `sudo apt-get autoremove mplayer`:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-6-base:i386 i965-va-driver:i386 liba52-0.7.4:i386
  libaa1:i386 libaacs0:i386 libacl1:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386
  libasound2:i386 libass5:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libattr1:i386 libaudio2:i386
  libaudiofile1:i386 libaudit1:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libavcodec-ffmpeg56
  libavcodec-ffmpeg56:i386 libavformat-ffmpeg56:i386 libavutil-ffmpeg54:i386
  libbdplus0:i386 libbluray1:i386 libbs2b0:i386 libbsd0:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386
  libc6:i386 libcaca0:i386 libcap2:i386 libcdio-cdda1:i386
  libcdio-paranoia1:i386 libcdio13:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libcrystalhd3:i386
  libcups2:i386 libdb5.3:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdca0:i386
  libdirectfb-1.2-9:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libdv4:i386
  libdvdnav4:i386 libdvdread4:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libenca0:i386
  libesd0:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfaad2:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386
  libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386 libgcc1:i386
  libgcrypt20:i386 libgif7:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgme0:i386 libgmp10:i386
  libgnutls30:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgpm2:i386
  libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4:i386
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libice6:i386 libicu55:i386 libidn11:i386
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libjson-c2:i386
  libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
  libkrb5support0:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libldb1:i386 liblircclient0:i386
  libllvm3.8:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmad0:i386 libmodplug1:i386 libmp3lame0:i386
  libmpeg2-4:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libncurses5:i386 libncursesw5:i386
  libnettle6:i386 libnuma1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386 libopenjpeg5:i386
  libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpam0g:i386
  libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libpopt0:i386
  libpostproc-ffmpeg53:i386 libpulse0:i386 libpython-stdlib:i386
  libpython2.7:i386 libpython2.7-minimal:i386 libpython2.7-stdlib:i386
  libreadline6:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 librtmp1:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
  libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386
  libschroedinger-1.0-0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libselinux1:i386
  libshine3:i386 libslang2:i386 libsm6:i386 libsmbclient:i386
  libsnappy1v5:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsoxr0:i386 libspeex1:i386
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssh-gcrypt-4:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
  libswresample-ffmpeg1:i386 libswscale-ffmpeg3:i386 libsystemd0:i386
  libtalloc2:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtdb1:i386 libtevent0:i386 libtheora0:i386
  libtinfo5:i386 libtwolame0:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libudev1:i386
  libuuid1:i386 libva1:i386 libvdpau1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386
  libvorbisidec1:i386 libvpx3:i386 libwavpack1:i386 libwbclient0:i386
  libwebp5:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-148:i386 libx265-79:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386
  libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxml2:i386 libxshmfence1:i386
  libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libxvmc1:i386
  libxxf86dga1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzvbi0:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386
  mplayer:i386 python:i386 python-minimal:i386 python-talloc:i386
  python2.7:i386 python2.7-minimal:i386 samba-libs:i386 tcpd
  va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386 vdpau-va-driver:i386 zlib1g:i386
Suggested packages:
  libasound2-plugins:i386 nas:i386 libbluray-bdj:i386 glibc-doc:i386
  locales:i386 firmware-crystalhd:i386 libdv-bin:i386 oss-compat:i386
  libdvdcss2:i386 pulseaudio-esound-compat:i386 rng-tools:i386 gnutls-bin:i386
  gpm:i386 krb5-doc:i386 krb5-user:i386 jackd2:i386 lirc:i386
  libportaudio2:i386 opus-tools:i386 libpam-doc:i386 pulseaudio:i386
  libsasl2-modules-otp:i386 libsasl2-modules-ldap:i386
  libsasl2-modules-sql:i386 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit:i386
  | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal:i386 speex:i386 mplayer-doc:i386
  netselect:i386 | fping:i386 python-doc:i386 python-tk:i386
  python2.7-doc:i386 binutils:i386 binfmt-support:i386 libfglrx-amdxvba1:i386
  libvdpau-va-gl1:i386 nvidia-vdpau-driver:i386
  nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver:i386
Recommended packages:
  xml-core:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bleachbit deluge deluge-common deluge-gtk dkms gimp gvfs-backends
  libavcodec-extra libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 libboost-python1.58.0 libglade2-0
  libgsoap8 libmikmod3 libportmidi0 libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0
  libsmbclient libsmpeg0 libtorrent-rasterbar8 libvncserver1 libvorbisidec1
  light-locker-settings lubuntu-software-center mplayer musescore-soundfont-gm
  python python-appindicator python-apt python-aptdaemon
  python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-attr python-cairo python-cffi-backend
  python-cryptography python-dbus python-defer python-enum34 python-gi
  python-glade2 python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-idna
  python-ipaddress python-libtorrent python-lxml python-minimal python-notify
  python-numpy python-openssl python-pam python-psutil python-pyasn1
  python-pyasn1-modules python-pygame python-pysqlite2 python-serial
  python-service-identity python-talloc python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core
  python-twisted-web python-xdg python-zope.interface python2.7
  python2.7-minimal samba-libs timgm6mb-soundfont virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
  virtualbox-qt vlc-plugin-samba
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-6-base:i386 i965-va-driver:i386 liba52-0.7.4:i386
  libaa1:i386 libaacs0:i386 libacl1:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386
  libasound2:i386 libass5:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libattr1:i386 libaudio2:i386
  libaudiofile1:i386 libaudit1:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libavcodec-ffmpeg56
  libavcodec-ffmpeg56:i386 libavformat-ffmpeg56:i386 libavutil-ffmpeg54:i386
  libbdplus0:i386 libbluray1:i386 libbs2b0:i386 libbsd0:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386
  libc6:i386 libcaca0:i386 libcap2:i386 libcdio-cdda1:i386
  libcdio-paranoia1:i386 libcdio13:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libcrystalhd3:i386
  libcups2:i386 libdb5.3:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdca0:i386
  libdirectfb-1.2-9:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libdv4:i386
  libdvdnav4:i386 libdvdread4:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libenca0:i386
  libesd0:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfaad2:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386
  libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386 libgcc1:i386
  libgcrypt20:i386 libgif7:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgme0:i386 libgmp10:i386
  libgnutls30:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgpm2:i386
  libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4:i386
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libice6:i386 libicu55:i386 libidn11:i386
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libjson-c2:i386
  libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
  libkrb5support0:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libldb1:i386 liblircclient0:i386
  libllvm3.8:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmad0:i386 libmodplug1:i386 libmp3lame0:i386
  libmpeg2-4:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libncurses5:i386 libncursesw5:i386
  libnettle6:i386 libnuma1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386 libopenjpeg5:i386
  libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpam0g:i386
  libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libpopt0:i386
  libpostproc-ffmpeg53:i386 libpulse0:i386 libpython-stdlib:i386
  libpython2.7:i386 libpython2.7-minimal:i386 libpython2.7-stdlib:i386
  libreadline6:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 librtmp1:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
  libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386
  libschroedinger-1.0-0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libselinux1:i386
  libshine3:i386 libslang2:i386 libsm6:i386 libsmbclient:i386
  libsnappy1v5:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsoxr0:i386 libspeex1:i386
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssh-gcrypt-4:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
  libswresample-ffmpeg1:i386 libswscale-ffmpeg3:i386 libsystemd0:i386
  libtalloc2:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtdb1:i386 libtevent0:i386 libtheora0:i386
  libtinfo5:i386 libtwolame0:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libudev1:i386
  libuuid1:i386 libva1:i386 libvdpau1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386
  libvorbisidec1:i386 libvpx3:i386 libwavpack1:i386 libwbclient0:i386
  libwebp5:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-148:i386 libx265-79:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386
  libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxml2:i386 libxshmfence1:i386
  libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libxvmc1:i386
  libxxf86dga1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzvbi0:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386
  mplayer:i386 python:i386 python-minimal:i386 python-talloc:i386
  python2.7:i386 python2.7-minimal:i386 samba-libs:i386 tcpd
  va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386 vdpau-va-driver:i386 zlib1g:i386
0 upgraded, 210 newly installed, 72 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 73,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 157 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

With `sudo apt-get remove mplayer`:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms libboost-python1.58.0 libglade2-0 libgsoap8 libmikmod3 libportmidi0
  libsdl-mixer1.2 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libsmpeg0 libtorrent-rasterbar8
  libvncserver1 musescore-soundfont-gm python-attr python-enum34 python-idna
  python-ipaddress python-pyasn1 python-pyasn1-modules timgm6mb-soundfont
  virtualbox-dkms
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-6-base:i386 i965-va-driver:i386 liba52-0.7.4:i386
  libaa1:i386 libaacs0:i386 libacl1:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386
  libasound2:i386 libass5:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libattr1:i386 libaudio2:i386
  libaudiofile1:i386 libaudit1:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libavcodec-ffmpeg56
  libavcodec-ffmpeg56:i386 libavformat-ffmpeg56:i386 libavutil-ffmpeg54:i386
  libbdplus0:i386 libbluray1:i386 libbs2b0:i386 libbsd0:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386
  libc6:i386 libcaca0:i386 libcap2:i386 libcdio-cdda1:i386
  libcdio-paranoia1:i386 libcdio13:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libcrystalhd3:i386
  libcups2:i386 libdb5.3:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdca0:i386
  libdirectfb-1.2-9:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libdv4:i386
  libdvdnav4:i386 libdvdread4:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libenca0:i386
  libesd0:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfaad2:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386
  libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386 libgcc1:i386
  libgcrypt20:i386 libgif7:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgme0:i386 libgmp10:i386
  libgnutls30:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgpm2:i386
  libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4:i386
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libice6:i386 libicu55:i386 libidn11:i386
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libjson-c2:i386
  libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
  libkrb5support0:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libldb1:i386 liblircclient0:i386
  libllvm3.8:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmad0:i386 libmodplug1:i386 libmp3lame0:i386
  libmpeg2-4:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libncurses5:i386 libncursesw5:i386
  libnettle6:i386 libnuma1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386 libopenjpeg5:i386
  libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpam0g:i386
  libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libpopt0:i386
  libpostproc-ffmpeg53:i386 libpulse0:i386 libpython-stdlib:i386
  libpython2.7:i386 libpython2.7-minimal:i386 libpython2.7-stdlib:i386
  libreadline6:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 librtmp1:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
  libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386
  libschroedinger-1.0-0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libselinux1:i386
  libshine3:i386 libslang2:i386 libsm6:i386 libsmbclient:i386
  libsnappy1v5:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsoxr0:i386 libspeex1:i386
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssh-gcrypt-4:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
  libswresample-ffmpeg1:i386 libswscale-ffmpeg3:i386 libsystemd0:i386
  libtalloc2:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtdb1:i386 libtevent0:i386 libtheora0:i386
  libtinfo5:i386 libtwolame0:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libudev1:i386
  libuuid1:i386 libva1:i386 libvdpau1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386
  libvorbisidec1:i386 libvpx3:i386 libwavpack1:i386 libwbclient0:i386
  libwebp5:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-148:i386 libx265-79:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386
  libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxml2:i386 libxshmfence1:i386
  libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libxvmc1:i386
  libxxf86dga1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzvbi0:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386
  mplayer:i386 python:i386 python-minimal:i386 python-talloc:i386
  python2.7:i386 python2.7-minimal:i386 samba-libs:i386 tcpd
  va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386 vdpau-va-driver:i386 zlib1g:i386
Suggested packages:
  libasound2-plugins:i386 nas:i386 libbluray-bdj:i386 glibc-doc:i386
  locales:i386 firmware-crystalhd:i386 libdv-bin:i386 oss-compat:i386
  libdvdcss2:i386 pulseaudio-esound-compat:i386 rng-tools:i386 gnutls-bin:i386
  gpm:i386 krb5-doc:i386 krb5-user:i386 jackd2:i386 lirc:i386
  libportaudio2:i386 opus-tools:i386 libpam-doc:i386 pulseaudio:i386
  libsasl2-modules-otp:i386 libsasl2-modules-ldap:i386
  libsasl2-modules-sql:i386 libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit:i386
  | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal:i386 speex:i386 mplayer-doc:i386
  netselect:i386 | fping:i386 python-doc:i386 python-tk:i386
  python2.7-doc:i386 binutils:i386 binfmt-support:i386 libfglrx-amdxvba1:i386
  libvdpau-va-gl1:i386 nvidia-vdpau-driver:i386
  nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver:i386
Recommended packages:
  xml-core:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bleachbit deluge deluge-common deluge-gtk gimp gvfs-backends
  libavcodec-extra libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 libsmbclient libvorbisidec1
  light-locker-settings lubuntu-software-center mplayer python
  python-appindicator python-apt python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  python-cairo python-cffi-backend python-cryptography python-dbus
  python-defer python-gi python-glade2 python-gobject python-gobject-2
  python-gtk2 python-libtorrent python-lxml python-minimal python-notify
  python-numpy python-openssl python-pam python-psutil python-pygame
  python-pysqlite2 python-serial python-service-identity python-talloc
  python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-twisted-web python-xdg
  python-zope.interface python2.7 python2.7-minimal samba-libs virtualbox
  virtualbox-qt vlc-plugin-samba
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-6-base:i386 i965-va-driver:i386 liba52-0.7.4:i386
  libaa1:i386 libaacs0:i386 libacl1:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386
  libasound2:i386 libass5:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libattr1:i386 libaudio2:i386
  libaudiofile1:i386 libaudit1:i386 libavahi-client3:i386
  libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libavcodec-ffmpeg56
  libavcodec-ffmpeg56:i386 libavformat-ffmpeg56:i386 libavutil-ffmpeg54:i386
  libbdplus0:i386 libbluray1:i386 libbs2b0:i386 libbsd0:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386
  libc6:i386 libcaca0:i386 libcap2:i386 libcdio-cdda1:i386
  libcdio-paranoia1:i386 libcdio13:i386 libcomerr2:i386 libcrystalhd3:i386
  libcups2:i386 libdb5.3:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdca0:i386
  libdirectfb-1.2-9:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libdv4:i386
  libdvdnav4:i386 libdvdread4:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libenca0:i386
  libesd0:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfaad2:i386 libffi6:i386 libflac8:i386
  libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386 libgcc1:i386
  libgcrypt20:i386 libgif7:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgme0:i386 libgmp10:i386
  libgnutls30:i386 libgomp1:i386 libgpg-error0:i386 libgpm2:i386
  libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsm1:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4:i386
  libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libice6:i386 libicu55:i386 libidn11:i386
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libjson-c2:i386
  libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386
  libkrb5support0:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libldb1:i386 liblircclient0:i386
  libllvm3.8:i386 liblzma5:i386 libmad0:i386 libmodplug1:i386 libmp3lame0:i386
  libmpeg2-4:i386 libmpg123-0:i386 libncurses5:i386 libncursesw5:i386
  libnettle6:i386 libnuma1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386 libopenjpeg5:i386
  libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpam0g:i386
  libpciaccess0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libpopt0:i386
  libpostproc-ffmpeg53:i386 libpulse0:i386 libpython-stdlib:i386
  libpython2.7:i386 libpython2.7-minimal:i386 libpython2.7-stdlib:i386
  libreadline6:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386 librtmp1:i386 libsamplerate0:i386
  libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386
  libschroedinger-1.0-0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libselinux1:i386
  libshine3:i386 libslang2:i386 libsm6:i386 libsmbclient:i386
  libsnappy1v5:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsoxr0:i386 libspeex1:i386
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssh-gcrypt-4:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
  libswresample-ffmpeg1:i386 libswscale-ffmpeg3:i386 libsystemd0:i386
  libtalloc2:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtdb1:i386 libtevent0:i386 libtheora0:i386
  libtinfo5:i386 libtwolame0:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libudev1:i386
  libuuid1:i386 libva1:i386 libvdpau1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386
  libvorbisidec1:i386 libvpx3:i386 libwavpack1:i386 libwbclient0:i386
  libwebp5:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libx264-148:i386 libx265-79:i386 libxau6:i386
  libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386
  libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386
  libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxml2:i386 libxshmfence1:i386
  libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxvidcore4:i386 libxvmc1:i386
  libxxf86dga1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 libzvbi0:i386 mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386
  mplayer:i386 python:i386 python-minimal:i386 python-talloc:i386
  python2.7:i386 python2.7-minimal:i386 samba-libs:i386 tcpd
  va-driver-all:i386 vdpau-driver-all:i386 vdpau-va-driver:i386 zlib1g:i386
0 upgraded, 210 newly installed, 52 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 73,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 177 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

How do I remove `mplayer` without both removing and installing unrelated packages? And why is this happening?